# CoreData - When I delete an core date entity from a list view, it reappears in the list blank

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I'm building a checklist app that uses core data. It has two main views:

1. **Home**: a list of Checklist entities using a @FetchRequest
2. **Checklist**: a child view of home that is passed a Checklist and stored in an @ObservedObject. A Checklist contains an array of Category entities, and each Category contains an array of Items.

However, when I delete an item in the Checklist view, it disappears momentarily and then reappears in the list, empty. If, however I navigate back to the parent view (Home) and into the view again, it's gone as expected, so somehow the view isn't updating as I expect.

I've experimented with how I pass the Checklist into the child view, using @ObservedObject and @StateObject, and a few other things but haven't gotten anything to work. I'm not sure if calling a separate @FetchRequest on the child view is the way to go (or how I'd do that...)

Here's an image of the issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AaNu.jpg

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
struct Home: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @FetchRequest(entity: Checklist.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Checklist.lastModifiedDate, ascending: false)]) var checklists: FetchedResults<Checklist>

    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(checklists, id: \.id){ checklist in
                    withAnimation {
                        ChecklistRowView(checklist: checklist)
                    }
                }
                .onDelete(perform: deleteChecklist)
                
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    private func deleteChecklist(offsets: IndexSet) {
        withAnimation {
            offsets.map { checklists[$0] }.forEach(viewContext.delete)

            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
}
            

struct ChecklistRowView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var checklist: Checklist
   
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationLink(destination: ChecklistView(checklist: checklist)){
            HStack(spacing: 16){
                Text(checklist.name ?? "")
            }
        }
    }
}
        
        
   

struct ChecklistView: View {

    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @ObservedObject var checklist: Checklist
    

    var body: some View {
        List {
            
            ForEach(checklist.categories) { category in
                Section(header: Text(category.name!)) {
                    ForEach(category.items) { item in
                        Text("\(item.name ?? "")")
                    }
                    .onDelete { indexSet in
                        let deleteItem = category.items[indexSet.first!]
                        category.removeFromItems(deleteItem)
                        viewContext.delete(deleteItem)

                        do {
                            try viewContext.save()
                        } catch {
                            print(error)
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    private func saveState() {
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
            print("saving")
        } catch {
            let nsError = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}

extension Checklist {
    @NSManaged public var createdDate: Date?
    @NSManaged public var icon: String?
    @NSManaged public var id: UUID?
    @NSManaged public var lastModifiedDate: Date?
    @NSManaged public var name: String?
    @NSManaged public var categories: [Category]
}

extension Category {
    @NSManaged public var id: UUID?
    @NSManaged public var name: String?
    @NSManaged public var checklist: Checklist?
    @NSManaged public var items: [Item]
}

extension Item {
    @NSManaged public var id: UUID?
    @NSManaged public var isChecked: Bool
    @NSManaged public var name: String?
    @NSManaged public var categories: NSSet?
}
```

Comment: Can you show your `deleteChecklist`method?

Comment: @NicolasElPapu Just added it. That function works as expected. When i delete a checklist it disappears.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this! **The issue is that the checklist can only see changes on its direct children**. Because items are grandchildren to the Checklist, the UI won't re-render after one is deleted.

Checklist > Categories > Items

I was able to solve this by making each section its own view observing its specific Category.

```
struct ChecklistView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @ObservedObject var checklist: Checklist
    
    var body: some View {
        List {            
            ForEach(checklist.categories) { category in
                SectionView(category: category)
            }
        }
        
    }
}

struct SectionView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @ObservedObject var category: Category
    
    var body: some View {        
        Section(header: Text(category.name!)) {
            ForEach(category.items) { item in
                Text("\(item.name ?? "")")
            }
            .onDelete {  
                // delete function goes here
            }
                    
        }
    }
}
```